# Finding and deleting all files that begin with . within a directory

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to find and delete all files that begin with `.` within a directory, and I know that I could do this via the command terminal but I'm VERY new to Ubuntu and don't quite know my way around commands yet. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by binary files?

Comment: Hidden files. Really, anything that begins with a .

Answer (score 8):

Hidden files don't have to be binary files.

You can use the following command to do this:

```
find /path/to/start/ -maxdepth 1 -name ".*" -type f -delete
```

This will search for files in `/path/to/start/` starting with a dot (`-name ".*"`, `*` means everything) without searching in sub directories (`-maxdepth 1`, change `1` to search deeper) only files (`-type f`) and will remove all the results (`-delete`).

**It's not always a good idea to delete these files!** Please be sure that you know what you're doing before executing this. Some files are hidden for a reason.

Comment: For more control, put argument `i` to `rm` command. This will require confirmation for each file to be deleted.

Comment: With GNU find, you can also use `-delete`.

Comment: Don't you mean `find /path/to/start/dir/ -maxdepth 1 -name ".*"  -type f -exec rm {} +` instead? with `-maxdepth 0` you won't find anything...

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You're right, my bad. I`ve updated my answer with both of your suggestions and verified that it's working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using shell globs and a for loop:

```
for file in .[^.]*; do rm "$file"; done
```

The `for file in GLOB; do ... done` will expand GLOB to all file names that match it, iterate through these files, sequentially saving each as `$file` and then run the commands between the `do` and `done` on them.

The glob `.[^.]*` will match all files beginning with a `.` and followed by a non-dot character (`[^.]`). The latter is needed to avoid matching `.` and `..`/.

So, for example:

```
$ ls -1A
.dot and spaces
.dotfile1
internal.dot
nodot
$ for file in .[^.]*; do rm -v "$file"; done
removed ‘.dot and spaces’
removed ‘.dotfile1’
$ ls -1A
internal.dot
nodot
```

If you want to run this for a directory other than the one you are currently in, just add the path to the glob. For example:

```
for file in /home/terdon/foobar/.[^.]*; do rm "$file"; done
```

Of course, the loop itself is not needed as @gniourf_gniourf [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456078/finding-and-deleting-all-files-that-begin-with-within-a-directory/456331?noredirect=1#comment600495_456331) in the comments, and you can simply delete all the files with

```
rm .[^.]*
```

Comment: You're also (trying) to delete folders that start with a `.`, whereas the OP mentions _files_. (Oh, then you will argue that [everything is a file in Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file)...).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf no, I will argue that `rm` has no effect on directories so whether the glob matches any or not is irrelevant.

Comment: That's why I specified (though parenthesized) _trying_ `:D`. You'll get some junk on stderr though. Also, why not, simply `rm /home/terdon/foobar/.[^.]*`? (oh, you will argue that this might potentially exceed the max number of arguments).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf yes, it might but that's indeed a good solution. I did not use it 'cause I thought that showing the loop would be useful. Added now, thanks.

Comment: Your glob `.[^.]*` is wrong. It won't match files/directories starting with two dots, e.g. `..hello` (yes, they're possible).

Comment: @Sasha well yes, that's what I say it does. You're right in that it won't match such files but I never claimed it did. Of course, since rm won't remove directories without -r, you could just use `. *` if that's what you need.